# Best way to read an xlsx file in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

So i have a xlsx (Excel File) inside my project and i have a javascript file where i want to only read its values
Whats the best way

My project structure is as following:

```
-src
--js
---js function
-files
--excelFile
```

Comment: "Vanilla" JavaScript doesn't even provide a way to read a file. You have to provide a bit more information about your situation/context. But generally, if you wanted to implement an xlsx reader from scratch, you'd start by looking into the file format.

Comment: thats why i asked here. because i want to know if there is a way

Comment: Deciphering proprietary formats ain't going to be easy in vanilla js... Would recommend you rather do that on the backend. See [PHPOffice](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) as an example.

Comment: No, if you don't know how to write the code then it's impossible. We're not a tutorial writing service

Comment: Can you not serve up the values you need via Google Sheets rather than Excel? Then you can access it with the Sheets API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pretty good module [available on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx).

In vanilla JS, you can import the module by adding this line to your file:

```
<script lang="javascript" src="dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
```

The link above will explain how to use the module to read the file contents, but you probably need to use the [Acquiring and Extracting Data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#acquiring-and-extracting-data) section.

There is also a good selection of demos, one of which explains how to read the file in your browser:

```
// XLSX is a global from the standalone script

(async() => {
  const url = "http://oss.sheetjs.com/test_files/formula_stress_test.xlsx";
  const data = await (await fetch(url)).arrayBuffer();
  /* data is an ArrayBuffer */
  const workbook = XLSX.read(data);

  /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
})();
```

Comment: after one day of investigation this solved my issue